# replacing linebreaks with <br> to use in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiwebview, line-breaks

I am pulling my data from sqlite and trying to show it in a UIWebView
I have tried

```
HTMLData = [container stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br />"];  

HTMLData = [HTMLData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"<br />"];  
HTMLData = [HTMLData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n"   withString:@"<br />"];  

[refweb loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
```

but none of them seems to be doing the job.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked

```
HTMLData = [container stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
```

what I did is I escaped the new line.
I didn't just click "enter" while writing the code, but I copied and pasted from the database output in the console.